# How do I programmatically hide the mouse cursor?

Tags: macos, terminal, bash, ui, cursor

I want to be able to hide the mouse cursor programmatically. I am okay with giving any required permissions to the script.

Is this operation possible on macOS?

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about this requirement? Just to confirm, you mean the flashing line in a text block, not the pointer? Do you want to remove it globally from all apps, or just from one particular app? And you want to be able to restore it as well, preferably without a restart? How will you know where you're typing?

Comment: I've made an [edit on the assumption / comments](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/348507/5472) that I feel is most logical @benwiggy - I don't think the OP wants to hide it in an app they are compiling or making.

Comment: @bmike "without the foreground app performing the hiding"....? <Confused>

Comment: So, video players and other apps can hide the cursor - OP wants to take over for all apps,  no matter which has focus and hide the cursor for a while, @benwiggy

Comment: @bmike Sounds like you're talking about the Pointer, not the Cursor...?

Comment: Quite possibly. I’ll adjust the edit. The foreground app is typically governing on both cursor control and the os sends the hide to backgrounded apps when focus leaves afaik. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nscursor/1527345-hide also, there are multiple cursors so hiding “the cursor” is a bit of a simplification IMO.

Comment: @benwiggy I mean the mouse symbol, not the caret symbol in the text boxes.

Answer (score 1):

so what i just did was to download cursorcerer pref pane.  then i unzipped it.  then showed package contents.  then simply double clicked the resource called cursorcerer.app.  now my cursor is invisible -- even after moving.  so you could call this app from the terminal.  quite debilitating in my environment, but could be very helpful in others!

http://doomlaser.com/cursorcerer-hide-your-cursor-at-will/

i was able to get my cursor back by running the preference pane.

Comment: I have this app, but as you said, you can’t get the cursor back. And I think the app doesn’t work in the latest macOS.

Comment: i wonder how he is doing it inside that app.  i showed contents of that, but nothing i can pick apart

Comment: The "how" is explained [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20150609013355/http://lists.apple.com:80/archives/carbon-dev/2006/Jan/msg00555.html), as linked from the product page mentioned in your answer.

Answer (score -1):

You can use applescript to set the cursor to the current background color of the terminal window:

```
tell application "Terminal"
    set invisibleColor to get background color of (get properties of (get startup settings))
    set properties of (get startup settings) to {cursor color:invisibleColor}   
end tell
```

Use `osascript` to execute applescript within a shell script.

Comment: I want to hide it for everything. The reason I want to do it from the terminal is to set a loop that continuously hides the cursor, as it becomes visible after moving it a little.

Comment: The original Title was "Hide the cursor from the terminal". At the time the question could be understood this way.